# How to hide Chrome "paused in debugger" overlay?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Some semi-recent update to Chrome now places an overlay on my webpage when paused at a breakpoint. I'm specifically trying to view the state of my page markup at this point, and the overlay is hiding exactly what I want to see!

Is there a way to turn off this markup?

Or is there a way to revert Chrome to a version that doesn't have this mis-feature?

Answer (score 35):

Now there is an option in Inspector's settings, just uncheck `Disable paused state overlay`: Go to Settings (F1), the Preferences tab (the first one) and it's the last option under Appearance (top left).

It is very usable with the [`setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 5000);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23096743/504270) trick to inspect elements that are visible only on hover.

Comment: To further clarify, you go to Settings (F1), the Preferences tab (the first one) and it's the first option under Appearance (top left). (tested in Chrome 60 and Opera 46).

Comment: would be pretty nice, if there was still a way to see that you're actually in pause mode...

Comment: and maybe in the same developer tools window @devman

Comment: Thanks for this tip! And for putting the debugger in pause, you can also open the Dev panel and the `Sources` tab, then press `F8` at any moment.

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this same issue, and I discovered that if I switch to the "Elements" tab and enable the element inspector (the button in the lower right with the magnifying glass icon) then the overlay is hidden. As you might expect, when you disable the element inspector again the "paused in debugger" message comes back, so I usually just leave the inspector enabled while I'm stepping through the debugger.

It may not be intuitive, but at least it works. If there are any other alternatives, I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 3):

If you see "Paused in Debugger" popup on Chrome 90.0+, then make sure to **enable** this setting under Preferences -> Appearance in Chrome Dev Tool to disable the popup.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore. I'm using Chrome 104.

Edit: I was looking for this option in Chrome > ... > Preferences. The option exists in DevTools Pane > ... > Preferences!