# How to deal with the overlay Paused in debugger while automated test execution using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Everytime I try to access this [website](http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm) and open [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) I am unable to inspect any of the elements through the Inspector as the UI is having an overlay along with a message **`Paused in debugger`**.

The [upvoted and accepted answer of this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013639/chrome-paused-in-debugger-issue) says to check the Source tab, check under the Event Listener Breakpoints panel if you've set any breakpoints under 'Mouse'. I have cross checked that none of the `Sources` -> `EventListenerBreakpoint` are set.

The [upvoted and accepted answer of this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013639/chrome-paused-in-debugger-issue) says to check if the little octagonal stop/pause sign (at lower left of Chrome "Sources") is colored (blue or purple). I am not sure why do I need to do that additionally for selected websites.

Snapshot:

[image: DebuggerPaused]

The [upvoted and accepted answer of this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478817/how-to-hide-chrome-paused-in-debugger-overlay) speaks about the *Manual Steps*.

All the solutions seem to point towards the manual process. But this issue seems to me the root cause behind [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) being unable to `getPageSource()`.

Code trials:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm");
```

Output: Chrome opens but doesn't navigates to the url.

So my questions are:

- In which case can `Paused in debugger` error occurs?
- Is it an error from the frontend development?
- How can I bypass this error during the *Automated Tests* through *Selenium*?

Comment: I have used `--headless`... it might have something to do with the profile...

Comment: The `Pause` was intentionally added to prevent you from analyzing the script in the page once Devtool is opened. It not an error and it doesn't affect the execution via Selenium.

Comment: Note that the the script in the page redirects to a different content when it's loaded with Selenium, most likely via fingerprinting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *In which cases can the `Paused in debugger` error occur?*

  Anytime you are accessing this page with the dev tools open.  The `debugger;` line will pause javascript execution, but browsers will ignore it if the dev tools are closed.
- *Is it an error from the frontend development?*

  In this case, no--they're deliberately trying to keep you out.  The purpose of this function is to pause execution and then redirect your browser to a different page if it takes longer than 100ms to resume.  I would speculate that this is designed to interfere with automated crawlers like selenium, because a regular user wouldn't be affected and a human developer can just hack around it.
- *How can I bypass this error during the Automated Tests through Selenium?*

My first recommendation would be to try running Selenium headlessly, if that's an option.  If not, **use the hotkey to resume execution (F8).**  You can use whatever method you like for generating a keypress; with the java.awt package it will look something like this:

```
Robot robot = null;
try
{
   robot = new Robot();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //handle failure
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F8);
```

Remember that you have to trigger this within 100ms, so use whatever logic you like to detect the block and respond quickly.  If you just want something quick and dirty, I would just make it spam F8 keypresses every 50ms for a period of time until you're certain the page has loaded.

**EDIT:** On further investigation, this page is extremely messy and hostile to anyone with the dev tools open.  There is not one but several functions that trigger `debugger;`and they get called repeatedly on a timer for as long as you're on the page.  Running headlessly seems like the best choice, unless you want to continue spamming F8 for the entire session.

Comment: you answer do not work, can you copy/paste full code please?

Comment: @sgrillon => why you think this answer will not work ? Key press event f8 will not be sent to dev tab?

Comment: With F8, `http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm` always white page

Comment: @sgrillon does it work for you without Selenium?  I couldn't even get the DNS to resolve until I switched to an Indian VPN.

Comment: @Miltios, yes `http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm` work for me without Selenium (by Chrome)

Comment: @AmitJain Did you get a chance to load this page using Selenium(with devtools open). You can't run the next line of code in your selenium script until the `.get` method returns the handle back to script, so in this case the your script does not get a chance to execute next line of code (which would be pressing F8).